# Efficiently reduce Series of lists to one dimensional list of non-null values in Python

Tags: python, list, series

Is there a better way to approach this problem?

**Problem**: reduce pandas series, *status*, to list *l* given below;

```
status = [[], [], [], [], ['200'], [], [], ['200']]
l = ['200', '200']
```

Here is how I solved it;

```
def flatten(x):
   if len(x)>0:
       return x[0]
   else: 
       return ""

status = status[status.apply(lambda x: flatten(x)) != ""]
l = [i for row in status.iloc[:] for i in row]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `itertools` package to efficiently flatten lists.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [[], [], [200], [], [200]]
})

list2d = df["a"].values
list(itertools.chain(*list2d))
```

Output:

```
[200, 200]
```

**Time testing**

First let's create a dummy 2d list:

```
list2d = [[_] for _ in range(100000000)]
```

Itertools flattening:

```
%%timeit
[*itertools.chain(*list2d)]
```

5.55 s ± 151 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

List comprehension flattening:

```
%%timeit​
[e for i in list2d for e in i]
```

6.34 s ± 228 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Comment: Thanks for your thorough response!

Answer (score 0):

```
status = [[], [], [], [], ['200'], [], [], ['200']]
l = [i for sublist in status for i in sublist]
```

output

```
['200', '200']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called list flattening:

```
l =[e for i in status for e in i]
```